# jar file could not run in 64 bit machine

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

i have developed a desktop application for my college project. I developed in 64 bit machine with NetBean IDE 7.0.1 of 32 bit and i have JDK of 32 bit, project runs perfectly form NetBean but when i converted into `.jar` it did not work, but same `.jar` file works in 32 bit machine. Anyone have idea about this thank in advance.

Comment: You'll have to describe what "does not work" means exactly.

Comment: Do you have a 64-bit J.R.E. installed, separate from the J.D.K.? This could be the culprit. In that case, you could be trying to load a 32-bit native library on a 64-bit J.R.E. when you try to execute the JAR file, which may not work.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace after this command - `java -jar yourjar.jar` ? Then we can give you a solution

Comment: JVM mismatch???  Make sure the client is running at least the same major version of the JVM as you have developed in

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, you can take code developed on a 64 bit machine and / or a 64 bit JVM, and run it on a 32 bit JVM ... and vice versa.  This applies whether or not you are using a JAR.

The fact that you are having trouble says that you've done something wrong.  However, without some more information, we'd be wasting our time speculating on what that might be.  "It did not work" is not enough to go on.  (It is like going to a doctor and saying, "I'm not well" and expecting him to cure you on that basis alone.)