# Cannot Run a executable jar compiled with 32 bit jdk in 64 bit machine

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit

I am having a java application which was creating using 32 bit jdk.

When i am running in 64 bit machine it is not working.

And when I run it using C:\Windows\SysWOW64 java -jar file.jar It is working properly.

So how do i run with out using command prompt.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662603/jar-file-could-not-run-in-64-bit-machine)?

Comment: It might be a duplicate, but the only answer on that massively downvoted question is 'you did something wrong.'

Comment: @Nagarajan What does "is is not working" mean? Does it run improperly, does it print an error message, does it crash?

Comment: Define 'not working'.

Comment: The jar file may have a library that is for 32 bit machines.  You'll need to download the 64 bit package online and replace the library.  Post the exact error message you get when you try to run it in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

on Behalf of nagarajan. The error we are getting is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Oracle
\product\11203\client_32-bit\bin\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a A
MD 64-bit platform